react navigation drawer reopen after navigate to screen in a nested stack naivgator
Issue: I'm experiencing an issue where the drawer navigator remains open when navigating between screens within a stack navigator. I have set up a drawer navigator that includes a stack navigator, but whenever I navigate to different screens within the stack, the drawer stays visible. I want the drawer to be hidden when navigating between screens in the stack.
navigation/navPhone/MainDrawer.js:
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

// Stack Navigator Screens
const PersonInfoScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View>
    <Button title='Go to Education' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Education')} />
    <Button title='Go to Users' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Users')} />
    <Text>Personal Screen</Text>
  </View>
);

const EducationScreen = () => <Text>Education Screen</Text>;
const UsersScreen = () => <Text>Users Screen</Text>;

// Create Stack Navigator
const TestStack = createStackNavigator({
  PersonInfo: PersonInfoScreen,
  Education: EducationScreen,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'PersonInfo',
});

// Create Drawer Navigator
const TestDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: TestStack,
  },
  Users: {
    screen: UsersScreen,
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Profile',
});

// Export the drawer navigator
export { TestDrawer };

and my App.js file is like following:
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { TestDrawer } from './navigation/navPhone/MainDrawer';

// Create Root Stack Navigator
const TestRootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: TestDrawer,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
  headerMode: 'none', // Hide header if you are using stack navigation
});

export default createAppContainer(TestRootStack);

and dependencies:

    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "3.8.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@hocs/debounce-handler": "0.5.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@shoutem/theme": "0.11.3",
    "@shoutem/ui": "^6.3.0",
    "apisauce": "1.0.3",
    "b4t-tcomb-form-native": "0.6.24",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.2.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.1.0 || ~1.2.0",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.18.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.18.2",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "lottie-ios": "4.2.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "ramda": "0.26.1",
    "re-reselect": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.7",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.204.0",
    "react-native-communications": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "9.0.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "0.1.24",
    "react-native-fs": "2.15.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "github:APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#pull/501/head",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.8.3",
    "react-native-looped-carousel": "0.1.13",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.12.5",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "7.5.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.9",
    "react-native-screens": "3.26.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view",
    "react-native-search-box": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-search-filter": "0.1.4",
    "react-native-share": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.3.0",
    "react-native-transformable-image": "https://bitbucket.org/xyz/react-native-transformable-image.git",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "~6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "https://abc@bitbucket.org/xyz/react-navigation-drawer.git",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",

i have tried updating the re-nanimated but not working
